# Why limit javascript script size to 25K in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am interested in client side scripting.  I have seen couple of references that suggest limiting client side script size to 2K LOC.

**Without getting into too much debate (and getting my question killed,) what are the reasons for limiting script size in a web page?  Similarly, what are the consequences of large scripts?**

**Thanks** in advance,  Dave Horsman

Comment: could you share those references?

Comment: Many libraries are bigger than that. You should generally concatenate your many small scripts into a bigger one, instead of the reverse.

Comment: i've never run into a recommendation like this. given the ubiquitous use of js in today's website and the average size of js frameworks (typically several dozen kb) i sincerely doubt that this advice is substantiated.

Comment: "Similarly, what are the consequences of large scripts" => longer downloads when the script isn't cached. That's all.

Comment: @Fabrizio I sorry I don't recall the first place I saw it.  The second was on this site where I asked about random script errors in IE8.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185170/ie8-expected-error-on-comment-lines

from Joe Frambach and appears in the comments.

Comment: Indeed it's true that a page should load as less js as possible, but in most of the cases 2kb are imho too limiting: if you load html5shiv you've already reached the quota...

Comment: @DHorse, in the comment he refers to 2kLOC -> 2000 lines of code, not 2kb of filesize

Comment: also, he refers to it as a "red flag", not a "hard limit".

Comment: @Fabrizio, oh... I stupidly didn't get the LOC reference.

Comment: Thanks to all, my question was answered quite adequately by the time it was killed.

Answer (score 3):

For mobile uses of js/css, iPhone won't cache components bigger that 25K in uncompressed size.

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#under25

Comment: OK that's good to know.  I was wading through that article but hadn't reached the IPhone comment.

Comment: I was going to delete the question but decided to leave it because of Johan Bouveng's answer.  I instead altered the original subject line to read 25K.

Answer (score 2):

That was sort of true of when 56k modems were normal. However, there is no reason to do that with broadband being so common. It's one thing to not include several MB of JavaScript, but you couldn't even include the most basic JavaScript libraries today with a constraint of 2kb for JavaScript.

Comment: There was nothing specific with big scripts in the era of modems. Big anything was just painful but the problem was never the size of the script, sometimes their number.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, I have merged all my scripts although I don't like it.  I use a very verbose style that results in a 500K size before minification.

Comment: @DHorse umm... WAT???

Comment: @DHorse I have very big web applications and I never got such a JS file. You might want to reconsider your style.

Comment: @dystroy You have good point.  The site is an educational site that includes using a verbose style for readability.  My plan is to minify it and see how large it still is.